# RubyMine - inotify(7) watch limit is too low

Tags: ide, rubymine, inotify

Everytime I start up my RubyMine I get an annoying message that say:

> inotify(7) watch limit is too low

but there's no hint on how to solve it.

I am running ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf (systemwide, do not search for /etc in RubyMine folder) to increase the inotify limit:

```
##### Fix: inotify(7) watch limit is too low  #####
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Then run

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Done!

PS: Restart your IDE...

Credit: https://rajeevkannav.blogspot.de/2014/12/rubymine-fix-inotify7-watch-limit-is_26.html